# motion effects missing from adobe premiere elements 10

Tags: premiere-elements

I'm a new user to Premiere Elements 10.

I want to rotate a video.

However, **the motion effect is not present in the effects panel**.

I have only recently installed Elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear in your panel as rotate, but if you go to your transform effect you will see roll and rotate options in there.

Comment: Thanks.  I can select Transform, and can click Apply, but double-clicking or right-clicking on Transform in the effects list, or in the applied effects list does nothing.

Comment: I found the edit effect button, cheers.